# Not able to play video.how to access a video path which is there in Downloads of Files in Android emulator

Tags: react-native

I drag and dropped my samplevideos folder into emulator then the file was available at Files/Downloads in emulator.

I was trying to access one of the video file from samplevideos file into my react native code

```
<Video source={{uri:"file:///Files:/Downloads/samplevideos/1.mp4"}}
          volume={50}
          resizeMode="cover"
          style={styles.videoStyle}
  />
```

[image: files folder screen shot]
[image: sample videos screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rn-fetch-blob`

> `dirs` -  This constant is a hash map containing commonly used
>   folders:

**Usage**

```js
const dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs
const filePath = `${dirs.DownloadDir}/samplevideos/1.mp4`
<Video source={{uri: filePath }}
          volume={50}
          resizeMode="cover"
          style={styles.videoStyle}
  />
```

Comment: firstly thanks for your time and efforts. i follow the steps what you mentioned but the video is not playing.

Comment: Thanks, after I have given permission it's playing. if i need to play list of videos then i given default paths  like const filePath = `${dirs.DownloadDir}/samplevideos/1.mp4`;
const filePath1 = `${dirs.DownloadDir}/samplevideos/2.mp4`;

const paths = [{path:filePath},{path:filePath1}] then it's taking last path then playing only last video path.if you know could you plz help me out